# Unable to load FXML when placed in a package

Tags: javafx-8, package, fxmlloader

I got this type of file hierarchy in JavaFXApplication5 project.[image]

Ive made another package for all the fxml files, so when project gets big it will be easier to find certain files.

Now in JavaFXApplication5 main class I have a line which Im sure causes an exception(java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException) when application is trying to run.

```
AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLNew.fxml"));
```

Im sure its because the "FXMLNew.fxml" root is wrong. But I dont know how to set it when is in another package...?

Or maybe these type of files should be put in normal folder?

Comment: There is no issue in placing your fxml files in another package

Comment: I tryed  `AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("windows/FXMLNew.fxml"));` but it doesnt work

Comment: Try an extra `/`. Something like this `getClass().getResource("/windows/FXMLNew.fxml")`

Comment: post it as an answer so everybody can see. Thank U :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load a fxml which is inside a package, use `/package-name/fxml-file-name.fxml`

For your case:

> AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/windows/FXMLNew.fxml"));